# How can I make my question more popular?

Tags: discussion

[I asked a question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/80642/do-i-need-permission-from-the-media-company-if-i-want-to-write-a-news-article-fr), which got little attention, some would even say worse than average. What are good ways to make it more popular (besides posting about it on Meta and making a bounty, which I don't have the reputation for)?

Comment: What specific popularity metric are you after? Views, comments, answers?

Comment: @Greendrake I mainly want comments and answers, views don't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make my question more popular?

Formulate a topic and/or scenario that is likely to wake the audience's interest. I intend no tautology in this guideline.

Your underlying question is unappealing because people would hardly ever encounter a situation that resembles the hypothetical scenario you formulate. By contrast, questions regarding employment or landlord-tenant issues are two examples of topics that resonate with many more people. That is because they are much likelier to identify in the question actual or potential concerns of theirs.

Also specifying a jurisdiction can make a difference for better or for worse. Questions involving US law will get more attention than questions about laws in Zimbabwe.

Occasionally, knowing the jurisdiction is crucial. For instance, US defamation law drastically differs from its South Korean counterpart whereas contract law is more uniform among jurisdictions.

Lastly, posting a question just for the sake of popularity might be pointless. Some of us decline to spend time on a question where the obviousness of the author's sake of popularity outweighs the value or relevance of the question itself.

Comment: I must disagree with part of this answer. We get many question s about copyright issues, and some of them get a good deal of attention. It seems that a good many people are interested in how expression can be protected, nd how it can be used by others with and without permission.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I am not saying that copyright law altogether is uninteresting or useless. My point is about the *set of factual premises* in the underlying question. That being said, some areas of law likely garner more interest than others in ways that the sheer number of views/votes/answers/comments might not portray. That is because the average person is likelier to be, or have been, in an employment or lease relation than to be interested in the implications of copyright law.

Answer (score 2):

### Show your work

We like to see that you have gone to *some* effort to learn about the legal issues that surround your question.

The question you asked is trivial to anyone who has read and understood Wikipedia’s page on copyright, not that Wikipedia is where you should end your research but it’s an ok place to start. It’s clear that you didn’t even do this trivial bit of research. Why should I put effort into answering a question you put no effort into asking?

Now, a question where you have done some research and don’t understand is a much better question.